# Sequelize : Object true has no method 'init'

Tags: node.js, express, has-many, sequelize.js

I use Sequelize with Express and start with this tutorial :
http://sequelizejs.com/articles/express

I want User to have any User (list of friends)

This is my User class:

```
    module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username : {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false,unique: true},
    email : {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false,unique:true,validate:{isEmail : true},msg:"Email must be valid."},
    password : {type:DataTypes.STRING,allowNull:false,validate:{len:[6,],msg:"Password length > 5."}},
    score : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    timeplay : DataTypes.BIGINT,
    timeaverage : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    nbrnotfoundword : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    nbrnotfound : DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, 
  {
    associate: function(models) {
        User.hasMany(models.User)

    }


    })

  return User
}
```

User.hasMany(models.User) gives me this error:

```
/home/damien/Documents/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/has-many.js:172
      this.through.init(this.through.daoFactoryManager)
                   ^
TypeError: Object true has no method 'init'
    at module.exports.HasMany.injectAttributes (/home/damien/Documents/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/has-many.js:172:20)
    at Mixin.hasMany (/home/damien/Documents/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/mixin.js:53:68)
    at Object.sequelize.define.associate (/home/damien/Documents/app/models/user.js:18:11)
    at module.exports.lodash.extend.sequelize (/home/damien/Documents/app/models/index.js:20:27)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/damien/Documents/app/models/index.js:18:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's more than likely due to your use of User before it's been defined.

Try this instead:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username : {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false,unique: true},
    email : {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false,unique:true,validate:{isEmail : true}, msg:"Email must be valid."},
    password : {type:DataTypes.STRING,allowNull:false,validate:{len:[6,],msg:"Password length > 5."}},
    score : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    timeplay : DataTypes.BIGINT,
    timeaverage : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    nbrnotfoundword : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    nbrnotfound : DataTypes.INTEGER
  });

  User.hasMany(User);

  return User;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem :

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize-mysql').sequelize
```

and not

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')
```